# How to write ~/.ssh/config when there is @(at symbol) in hostname?

Tags: ssh

I am given `ssh myname@nc-3031@ssh.cn-zhongwei-1.paracloud.com -p 22022` command to access the server. But this config in my `~/.ssh/config` does not work:

```
Host myserver
  HostName nc-3031@ssh.cn-zhongwei-1.paracloud.com
  User myname
  Port 22022
```

The result of `ssh myserver` is:

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

So there must be some problems with my config, and I think it has something to do with `myname@nc-3031@ssh.cn-zhongwei-1.paracloud.com`.  How to write ~/.ssh/config when there is `@` in the hostname?

Comment: The keyword `hostname` is missing in front of your hostname. Btw. `@` isn't a legal character in a hostname, so there is no problem with ssh. It's very unlikely, that `nc-3031@` is part of the hostname

Answer (score 0):

`Username` should be `myname@nc-3031`.

```
Host myserver
  HostName ssh.cn-zhongwei-1.paracloud.com
  User myname@nc-3031
  Port 22022
```

This works for me.